Automate chain call of endpoints within APIMAN
I have multiple endpoints that output different values. Some values of the first call are needed for the other call to work. Is it possible to call, in a certain order, the different endpoints within APIMAN. The objective is to pass from a series of endpoint call, to only one. Which settings I have to do in APIMAN to do so?
I looked at the plans/policies part of the documentation but I don't understand how it works exactly and what to look for.

Can you please clarify whether you are referring to WSO2 or Apiman? These are completely different API Management platforms.

I just modified. I talk about APIMAN

@MarcSavy, I modified the question. I'm talking about APIMAN

Are you trying to write a custom policy for the Apiman Gateway? Are you trying to interact with Apiman Manager's API? I am not sure what you are referring to.
